# Can I specify a multiline context variable/parameter when {% include %}ing a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I know that it is possible to set context variables when including a Django template from another template using

```
{% include "default_table.html" with table_header=table_header1 table_data=table_data1 %}
```

or

```
{% with "My data" as table_data %}
    {% include 'default_table.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

My issue with this is that both approaches don't let me define multiline variables (unless they are based on a previous multiline variable of course).

My specific usecase is this

```
<!-- widget.html -->
<div class="box">
    <div class="title">{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="title">{{ body }}</div>
</div>
```

and I'd like to be able to set a longer text for the `body` context variable. This will make is possible for me to reuse common widget HTML in various places. Can this be done?

I've been searching a bit on http://djangosnippets.org for an über `{% with ... %}` template tag, but haven't found any so far.

Answer (score 0):

This Django snippet kinda solves my issue: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1860/ But I'd love to be able to set context variables instead of defining `{% localblock step_ready_js %}{% endlocalblock %}` in my widget HTML.